# scrape website for PDFs within a number of links

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pdf, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm new to Python (I usually use R but heard Python is better for scraping PDFs).
I'm trying to get the PDFs from all search results from this website: https://www.coroners.nsw.gov.au/coronial-findings-search.html?searchtext=death%20in%20custody&searchYear=All

I was able to get code to run that can download the PDF if I give it the link to the individual e.g., https://coroners.nsw.gov.au/coroners-court/download.html/documents/findings/2023/Inquest_into_the_death_of_CJ.pdf

But I can't get it to the stage of automating the process to go from the search result page to get the PDF within the hyperlink.
This is my most recent unsuccessful attempt - any advice would be very much appreciated!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# chromedriver
path_to_chromedriver = ''

# create a new Chrome browser instance
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)

# go to the webpage
driver.get('https://www.coroners.nsw.gov.au/coronial-findings-search.html?searchtext=death%20in%20custody&searchYear=All')

try:
    # wait for the findings-row to load
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'findings-row')]//a")))

    # find the download button using the given absolute xpath
    download_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/ul/li/div[1]/a")))

    # interact with the download button (e.g., click the button)
    download_button.click()

except TimeoutException:
    print("Loading took too much time!")

# close the browser
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! Thanks for the help

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base = "https://www.coroners.nsw.gov.au/coronial-findings-search.html?searchtext=death%20in%20custody&searchYear=All"
home = "https://www.coroners.nsw.gov.au"

while base:
    page = requests.get(base)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

    # Check for the existence of a "Next" link and get its URL, if it exists.
    next_page_div = soup.find('div', class_='next-pagination')
    next_page_link = next_page_div.find('a') if next_page_div else None
    base = urljoin(home, next_page_link.get('href')) if next_page_link else None

    # Find all <a> tags inside <h4> tags.
    urls = [h4.find('a').get('href') for h4 in soup.find_all('h4')]

    # Fetch the URLs.
    for url in urls:
        basename = os.path.split(url)[-1]
        print(basename)

        # First, we have to fetch the bounce page that has the actual link.
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
        link = soup.find('a', class_='gel-download-arrow')
        final = urljoin(home, link.get('href'))

        # Now that we have the link, fetch the file.
        p1 = requests.get(final)
        with open(basename,'wb') as f:
            f.write(p1.content)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't actually need Selenium for this.  These pages are not dynamic.  Here is a script using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` that does the job.  Note that I put a "break" in the final loop so it stops after one file; you will probably want to remove that.

The task is made a bit more complicated because the links on the search page do not actually fetch the files.  They go to a "jump" page that has a "Download" button.  This code fetches the "jump" page and then fetches the file itself.

```
import os
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = "https://www.coroners.nsw.gov.au/coronial-findings-search.html?searchtext=death%20in%20custody&searchYear=All"
home = "https://www.coroners.nsw.gov.au"
page = requests.get(base)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

# Find all <a> tags inside <h4> tags.

urls = []
for h4 in soup.find_all('h4'):
    atag = h4.find('a')
    urls.append( atag.get('href') )

# Fetch the URLs.

for url in urls:
    basename = os.path.split(url)[-1]
    print(basename)

    # First, we have to fetch the bounce page that has the actual link.

    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
    link = soup.find('a', class_='gel-download-arrow')
    final = home + link.get('href')

    # Now that we have the link, fetch the file.

    p1 = requests.get(final)
    with open(basename,'wb') as f:
        f.write(p1.content)
    break
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked to scrape the first ten results. Are you able to show me how to get the results from the other search result pages (there are 801 PDFs all together) - I tried to create a while loop to fetch new pages, but it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way

Implementation:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.coroners.nsw.gov.au/coronial-findings-search.html?searchtext=death%20in%20custody&searchYear=All')

search_results = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.search-result-content')))
documents = search_results.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.paginationList>li')
print(f"Total documents on the page: {len(documents)}")

doc_url = [doc.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h4.search-font> a').get_attribute('href') for doc in documents]

for i in doc_url:
    print(f"Downloading: {i.split('/')[-1]}")
    driver.get(i)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.download-button')))
    driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('div.download-button>a').click()")
    time.sleep(2)

time.sleep(5)
```

output:

```
Total documents on the page: 10
Downloading: Inquest_into_the_death_of_Brandon_Clark._pdf.pdf
Downloading: Inquest_into_the_death_of_CJ.pdf
Downloading: Inquest_into_the_death_of_Azhar_Abdul.pdf
Downloading: Inquest_into_the_death_of_John_Cribb.pdf
Downloading: Inquest_into_the_death_of_Anthony_Gilbert.pdf
Downloading: Findings_-_Inquest_into_the_death_of_Gordon_Copeland_-_18_April_2023.pdf
Downloading: Inquest_into_the_death_of_John_Dodd.pdf
Downloading: Final_-_Findings_Inquest_into_the_death_of_Stanley_Russell_April_2023_14_April.pdf
Downloading: Inquest_into_the_death_of_KT.pdf
Downloading: Inquest_into_the_death_of_LT.pdf
```

### Approach followed:

- *Wait for the desired web element container holding all the data to get loaded to find/locate it*.

  ```
  search_results = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.search-result-content')))
  ```
- *Find all the individual target data points within the container.*

  ```
  documents = search_results.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul.paginationList>li')
  ```
- *Next, iterate over the web element containing the list of data points to parse, extract the URL, and put them all in the list.*

  ```
  doc_url = [doc.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h4.search-font> a').get_attribute('href') for doc in documents]
  ```
- *Finally, loop over the list of URLs*,

  - get to the page,
  - wait for the target web element (`Download`) to be available on the page,
  - and execute the query to perform a click to download the file.

This is how you can download all the documents on a single page, and the same can be replicated on multiple pages.

I hope this solves your problem.